# GeoCoder Nominatim in TkinterMapView is Failing because of "Max retries exceeded with url"

Tags: python, tkinter, geocode, tkintermapview

I am making a app that pulls addresses from an Excel sheet (using Openpyxl), turns those addresses into coordinates (using Geocoder), and places a marker at those coordinates on a `TkinterMapView`.

When I first built it, the map worked perfectly, but then the map just started crashing with the error:

> "Max retries exceeded with url"

I don't know if I upgraded or changed something that is causing the issue.

- I've uninstall and reinstall all modules that I use in the app.
- I have destroyed the Virtual Environment that I was working in and pulled everything over to a new Virtual Environment.
- One forum recommended upgrading OpenSSL, which I did, still didn't work.

Any Ideas on how to fix this request issue?

Here's the Code for the **Workbook** to **Geocodes** to **Marker on Map**:

```
wB = load_workbook('LocationsMM.xlsx')
wS = wB.active
column_C = wS['C']
#-------------------------------------------
CountSet = 0
def SetCounter():
    global CountSet
    CountSet += 1
for SETcell in column_C:
    AddressCellC = SETcell.value
    loc = Nominatim(user_agent="Mike")
    getSETLoc = loc.geocode(AddressCellC, timeout=10)
    getSETLoc_attrib_list = [x for x in dir(getSETLoc) if not x.startswith(('__','__')) and not callable(getattr(getSETLoc, x))]
    for atty in getSETLoc_attrib_list:
        SETlat1 = getSETLoc.latitude
        SETlong1 = getSETLoc.longitude
        Marker2 = MAP.set_marker(SETlat1, SETlong1, "SET", 
                                marker_color_circle="white", 
                                marker_color_outside = "red", 
                                text_color = "black", 
                                command = contactInfo)

    T = True
    while T == True:
        SetCounter()
        T = False
    print("SET", CountSet)    
#############################################    
#Holding List############################################
wB = load_workbook('HoldingCats(2).xlsx')
wS = wB.active
column_b = wS['B']
#column_Name = wS['A']
#-------------------------------------------
CountHC = 0
def HolcatCounter():
    global CountHC
    CountHC += 1
for cell in column_b:
    AddressCellB = cell.value
    loc = Nominatim(user_agent="Mike")
    getLoc = loc.geocode(AddressCellB)
    getLoc_attrib_list = [x for x in dir(getLoc) if not x.startswith(('__','__')) and not callable(getattr(getLoc, x))]
    for atty in getLoc_attrib_list:
        lat1 = getLoc.latitude
        long1 = getLoc.longitude
        Marker1 = MAP.set_marker(lat1, long1, "HolCat", 
                                marker_color_circle="white", 
                                marker_color_outside = "black", 
                                text_color = "black", 
                                command = contactInfo)

    T = True
    while T == True:
        HolcatCounter()
        T = False
    print("HOLCAT", CountHC)
```

**Here is the ERROR:**

```
/usr/bin/env /Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/bin/python /Users/jawn/
.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.0.0-darwin-x64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/laun
cher 53842 -- /Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/CC\ Excel3Me.py 
2024-02-14 16:38:56.154 Python[86087:674886] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to /var/folders/23/r0y4j88j0t9bktj2bzp_8n3w0000gn/T/org.python.python.savedState
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1096, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 782, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 470, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 514, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1046, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1321, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=ADDRESS&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py", line 482, in _request
    resp = self.session.get(url, timeout=timeout, headers=headers)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=ADDRESS&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/CC Excel3Me.py", line 399, in <module>
    getSETLoc = loc.geocode(AddressCellC, timeout=10)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/nominatim.py", line 297, in geocode
    return self._call_geocoder(url, callback, timeout=timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py", line 368, in _call_geocoder
    result = self.adapter.get_json(url, timeout=timeout, headers=req_headers)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py", line 472, in get_json
    resp = self._request(url, timeout=timeout, headers=headers)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jawn/Desktop/c/Locations/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py", line 494, in _request
    raise GeocoderUnavailable(message)
geopy.exc.GeocoderUnavailable: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=ADDRESS&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))
```